# How to read a message from a file, modifying only words?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following text:

```
My name   is   myName. I love 
stackoverflow   .   
Hi, Guys!   There is more than one space after "Guys!" 123 
And also after "123" there are 2 spaces and newline.
```

Now I need to read this text file as it is. Need to make some actions only with alphanumeric words. And after it I have to print it with changed words but spaces and newlines and punctuations unchanged and on the same position. When changing alphanumeric words length remains same. I have tried this with  library checking for alphanumeric values, but code get very messy. Is there anyother way?

Comment: Another to what? How did you tackle this problem, and what is "messy" for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file line-by-line with `fgets()` function. It will fill char array and you can work with this array, e.g. iterate over this array, split it into alnum words; change the words and then write fixed string into new file with "`fwrite()`" function.

If you prefer C++ way of working with files (iostream), you can use [istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/). It will save spaces; but it will consume "\n". If you need to save even "\n" (it can be '\r' and '\r\n' sometimes), you can use  [istream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/).

Comment: It's c++. Why do it the C-way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at Boost Tokenizer. It can break of a string into a series of tokens and iterate through them. The following sample breaks up a phrase into words:

```
int main()
{
   std::string s = "Hi, Guys!   There is more...";
   boost::tokenizer<> tok(s);
   for(boost::tokenizer<>::iterator beg = tok.begin(); beg != tok.end(); ++beg)
   {
       std::cout << *beg << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

But in your case you need to provide a TokenizerFunc that will break up a string at alphanumeric/non-alphanumeric boundaries.

For more information see [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) documentation and implementation of an already provided char_separator, offset_separator and escaped_list_separator.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code got messy is usually because you didn't break down your problem in clear functions and classes. If you do, you will have a few functions that each do precisely one thing (not messy). Your `main` function will then just call these simple functions. If the function names are well chosen, the `main` function will become short and clear, too.

In this case, your main function needs to do:

- Loop: Read every line of a file
- On every line, check if and where a "special" word occurs.
- If a special word occurs, replace it

Extra hints: a line of text can be stored as a `std::string` and can be read by `std::getline(std::cin, line)`